how to fix knocking in well system
My home is on a private well.   The line comes into the house from the well, roughly 15 feet from our house and enters in the basement about three feet above the floor.   The pvc line then goes up, along the ceiling of the basement, about 30-40 feet, then down to the tank.
Whenever the pump shuts off, the pvc pipe (1 1/4") vibrates like crazy for a second or two and makes a lot of noise.
I've put in hangers and pipe insulation all over to quiet it down, but that's only a temp solution.  I've looked into a constant pressure system and have gotten quotes for $10k, so that's not happening.
My two options are:
Putting in an automatic air vent somewhere in the pvc that runs along the ceiling
or
rerunning the entire pvc supply line along the floor instead of the ceiling, in the hopes that it fixes the problem.
Are either of these good solutions, or am I missing anything?
I've had a couple plumbers out and no one has suggested anything that could help.
thanks

Does the seem to come on and off often/rapidly when using water?  Do you have a good working air bladder in the tank/does it hold air?

I meant to add pump before seem. Look up water logged pressure tanks.   I will get this edit right sometime.

install a back flow preventer

Normally the pump will come on almost every time a toilet is flushed, or if the water is being run, say in a shower, maybe every 90 seconds to 2 minutes.   Not sure if that's normal or not, but it's been that way since we've lived here the last 3 years.

The tank is only a year and a half old, so I'm hoping the bladder isn't the culprit or contributing to the issue.

I will check out a back flow preventer.
